# SPARK individual upgrade to 2.1.0 in Ambari HDP 2.5.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop2, ambari

I want to upgrade my SPark component to 2.1.0 from its default 2.0.x.2.5 in Ambari.

I am using HDP 2.5.0 with Ambari 2.4.2.

Appreciate any idea to achieve this.

Comment: Is upgrading to HDP 2.6 an option?

Comment: No actually we are supposed to update only individual service.

Answer (score 1):

HDP 2.5 shipped with a technical preview of Spark 2.0, and also Spark 1.6.x. If you do not want to use either of those versions and you want Ambari to manage the service for you then you will need to write a custom service for the Spark version that you want. If you don't want ambari to manage the Spark instance you can follow similar instructions as provided on the [Hortonworks Community Forum](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/53029/how-to-install-and-run-spark-20-on-hdp-25-sandbox.html) to manually install Spark 2.x without management.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Ambari (maybe 3.0) probably will support per-component upgrade/multiple component versions

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-12556 for details.